# How to solve a bad bind variable for an oracle trigger>?

Tags: oracle

When I create the below tables and trigger, I'm getting a compiling bad bind error.

```
CREATE TABLE cteam_ExpenseItem (
    ExpenseNo NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE cteam_ExpenseReport (      
    ERSubmitNo NUMBER
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cteam_Trigger3
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ExpenseNo ON cteam_ExpenseItem
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    vA  cteam_ExpenseItem.ExpenseNo%TYPE;

BEGIN

SELECT ExpenseNo
INTO vA  
FROM cteam_ExpenseItem
WHERE ExpenseNo = :NEW.ERSubmitNo;


   IF vA <= ERSubmitNo THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Error');
  END IF;
END;
```

I'm getting a bad bind error for 'NEW.ERSUBMITNO'.
How do I go about solving this?

Comment: There is no column `ERSubmitNo` in the table `cteam_ExpenseItem` on which the trigger is on. Therefore `:NEW.ERSubmitNo` fails. Maybe you rather want the trigger to be on `cteam_ExpenseReport`?

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

As @stickybit pointed out in a comment, there is no `ERSubmitNo` column on `cteam_ExpenseItem`. But even if there was, you don't want to try reading from the table your trigger is defined on - you're likely to get a `TABLE IS MUTATING, TRIGGER CANNOT SEE IT` error. Instead, use the value from the `:OLD` pseudo-row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cteam_Trigger3
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ExpenseNo ON cteam_ExpenseItem
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    vA  cteam_ExpenseItem.ExpenseNo%TYPE;

BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ExpenseNo <= :NEW.ExpenseNo THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Error');
  END IF;
END;
```

I'm *guessing* that's what you're trying to do - if not you can fold, spindle, or mutilate as necessary. :-)